# Index in rails loop not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to loop from 1 to 4.  It's working.  However, I want the index of the loop so I know which title to give based on where we are in the loop.
Currently it writes out 1 four times.  So I have "Not quite Gallifrey" as a table head four times.

```
                     <%(1..4).each.with_index do |i, index|%>
                        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <%if index = 1 %>
                                        <th colspan=3>Not quite Gallifrey</th>
                                    <%elsif index = 2 %>
                                        <th colspan=3>Careless Whisper</th>
                                    <%elsif index = 3 %>  
                                        <th colspan=3>Take off, you hoser</th>             
                                    <%elsif index = 4 %> 
                                        <th colspan=3>California Love</th>
                                    <%end%>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th><%=index%>Place</th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Wins</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                               ...tablebody here
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    <%end%>
```

I would expect to `<%=index%>` or `<%=i%>` and get the number written out.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
ths = ["Not quite Gallifrey", "Careless Whisper", "Take off, you hoser", "California Love"]

<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <% ths.each do |th| %>
                <th colspan=3><%= th %></th>
            <% end %>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <% (1..ths.length).each |i| %>
                <th><%= i %> Place</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Wins</th>
            <% end %>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I thought that you actually didn't want 4 tables, but if you do, then just move `<% ths.each do |th| %>`, and remove this loop `<% (1..ths.length).each |i| %>`

Comment: Now that is a thing of beauty.  I'm definitely going to do this and +1 for it.  However, I'm still baffled by why my `.each.with_index` isn't giving me the index.

Comment: There must be something weird with your code, aside from the loop, because, if you execute it in a ruby interpreter, it works fine.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty confused.  I built a loop just below this and it worked fine.  I didn't think I had anything else in there but I must have been doing something wrong.  Thanks for your help!